# Sequence to sequence machine learning / NMT - converting numbers into words

Tags: natural-language-processing, tensorflow, keras

I want to do some sequence to sequence modelling on source data that looks like this:

```
/-0.013428/-0.124969/-0.13435/0.008087/-0.269241/-0.36849/
```

with target data that looks like this:

```
Dont be angry with the process youre going through right now
```

Both are of indeterminate lengths, and the lengths of target and source data aren't the same. What I'd like to do is have a prediction model where I can input similar numbers and have it generate texts based on the target training data.

I started off doing character level s2s, but the output of the model is too nonsensical even at 2-5k epochs. So I've been looking into word level s2s and NMT, but the tutorials always assume strings of text as the target and source, and I keep running into roadblocks trying to preprocess the text, when all the tutorials assume a certain syntax/set of characters. This is my first try at ML, and some of the tutorials really throw me out with the text preprocessing requirements.

Am I going down the right avenue looking at word level/NMT stuff? And is there a tutorial I've missed for something like what I'm trying to build?